# How can I remove icon covering clock in GNOME Shell top bar?

Tags: 18.04, xorg, gnome-shell, indicator

Zoom icon is covering the clock. Other icons do the same.
[image]

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 using GNOME on Xorg.

How do I make sure this does not happen?

Comment: This doesn't look like the default GNOME Shell panel. Please [edit] your question to add your Ubuntu version and the extensions that you are using. Does the issue persist if you disable all extensions?

Comment: @pomsky What I mean is that the OP either uses too many indicators (using GNOME Shell extensions probably), as you state in your answer, or a GNOME Shell extension that moves the clock to the right or both. If they are using extensions, the problem might be related to their interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this cropped screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2aFU.png) that you have added to the question, it looks like you have *too many* indicator icons in your top-right  status area. Also the fact that the default spacing between the icons in the status area is quite large made the matter worse in your case.

So you might want to reduce the spacing between the icons in the status area first. You can do that by using the [**Status Area Horizontal Spacing**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/) GNOME extension (Refer to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) to learn about installing and managing GNOME Shell extensions):
[image: Status Area Horizontal Spacing GNOME extension]

Also might want disable/remove unnecessary icons from the the status area.